# wp_register_script was called incorrectly

Tags: wp-register-script

I created this theme and it worked on my site without any problem. When I moved it to another server, I get `wp_register_script was called incorrectly.` error.

I scanned my source code and I didn't use any wp_register_script ... however I am suspecting that it is reacting to this ...

```
function add_script_code() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', base_url('source/js/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js'), false, '1.3.0', TRUE );
    wp_enqueue_script('less', base_url('source/js/less-1.3.0.min.js'), false, '1.3.0', TRUE );
    wp_enqueue_script('vars', base_url('source/js/vars.js'), false, '1.3.0', TRUE);
    wp_enqueue_script('function', base_url('source/js/function.js'), false, '1.3.0', TRUE );
}

//add_action('admin_init', 'add_script_code');
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_script_code')
```

My code base is in github. The functions folder contains my functions for the theme.

https://github.com/abarcenas29/dmp-v4

Base url is a function I created.

```
function base_url($url) {
        return get_bloginfo('template_url').'/'.$url;
    }
```

Comment: Particularly, I've never seen this `base_url` used before...

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the fucntion for it. It is also on the default_func.php file. @brasofilo

Comment: I believe that `wp_enqueue_script()` code should be attached to an early hook, like `wp_head` or `wp_enqueue_scripts`, and the fifth argument will load the script in footer

Comment: Why did my theme work on my other server then? This error only happened when I move it in another wp install. @bungeshea Also, could you cite and example?

Comment: I don't know why you are receiving different server responses, but see my answer below for guidance on how to fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook your function into either `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `init`. `wp_footer` is too late to  enqueue scripts; they need to be enqueued before the `wp_head()` function is called.

The fifth argument of the [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function, when set to true, will load the script in the page footer instead of header. From [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script):

> You have to enqueue your script before wp_head is run, even if it will be placed in the footer

Comment: I tried editing ... add_action('wp_footer', 'add_script_code') to add_action('init', 'add_script_code') but still gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are the WordPress versions the same on both servers? I believe the notice was added in version 3.3. Also, bungeshea is right about enqueueing your script before wp_head is run - meaning you should be hooking into either `init` or `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

oh yeah, the 3rd argument should be an `array` not `boolean` so the call should look like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('function', base_url('source/js/function.js'), array(), '1.3.0', TRUE );
```

Comment: You should actually use `false` for the third argument if your script has no dependencies. See [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for details

Comment: @bungeshea: the Codex does not use `false` ;) The parameter type clearly says it should be an `array`. In fact, the default value for the 3rd paramter is an empty `array()` which is used when there are no dependencies.

Comment: Read again: Array of handles of any script that this script depends on (scripts that must be loaded before this script). **false if there are no dependencies**

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. My theme was written in short tags. My server short tags was off. So I just converted my theme to use `<?php` and everything worked.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Please accept your answer using the tick to the left of your answer