# Trying to use wp_register_script/style and enqueu them from an array - getting an error

Tags: plugins, themes, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

here is what i got so far:

```
  // my array
$this->headersArray = array(
    array('handle' => 'buy_mobile_funcs', 'src' => 'jsFunctions', 'extention' => 'js', 'deps' => '', 'media' => ''),

    array('handle' => 'css_main_style', 'src' => 'main_style', 'extention' => 'css', 'deps' => '', 'media' => 'screen')
);

// registering 
foreach($this->headersArray as $singleHeader){
    if($singleHeader['extention'] == 'js'){
        wp_register_script(
            $singleHeader['handle'], plugins_url('scripts/'.$singleHeader['src'].'.'.$singleHeader['extention'],__FILE__), 
            (!empty($singleHeader['deps']))? $singleHeader['deps']  : ''
        );
    }else{
        wp_register_style(
            $singleHeader['handle'], plugins_url('css/'.$singleHeader['src'].'.'.$singleHeader['extention'],__FILE__), 
            (!empty($singleHeader['deps']))? $singleHeader['deps']  : ''
        );
    }
}

// enqueuing 
foreach($this->headersArray as $singleHeader){
    if($singleHeader['extention'] == 'js'){
        wp_enqueue_script($singleHeader['handle']);
    }else{
        wp_enqueue_style( $singleHeader['handle'], '', '', '', $singleHeader['media'] );
    }
}
```

I know i could combine the 2 foreach. however i have a reason to keep it as it is now which is not relevant to the questions.

Error:

```
Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home1/stodeckc/public_html/orgadsite/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3012
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: 1. As is, this seems like more of a PHP question. 2. You should probably explain *what* the error is instead of asking us to guess. 3. Why are you making this more complicated than it should be?

Comment: it aint more complicated then it should be. instead of loading 8-15 different script manually i am doing it dynamically. updated the post with the error

Comment: It is more complicated because you're adding more lines of code, reducing readability while (in my opinion, of course) not getting anything out of it.  Manually enqueing a script is 1 line of code. Based on your error code, this is a duplicate of: [#78836](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78836/wp-register-script-was-called-incorrectly) and [#49339](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49339/notice-that-the-wp-enqueue-style-is-not-being-called-correctly), not to mention having plenty of Google search results for this exact error.

Comment: Well, indeed, googling for the error code is rule zero of debugging... But if there are 8/15 scripts, I don't see why not doing like you are. Suggestion, you already checked for the extension, why not reduce to `[src].'.js',__FILE__)`?

Comment: helgathevikin - its not 1 line per script. its 2 lines for registering and enqueue. and if you have 8-15 scripts to load thats 16-30 lines/ and later editing them is a mass. instead you have them all in 1 array where they are organized. " that is what you get from it"

Comment: @NetaMeta Read your "error" message again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the "Error Message" (which is in fact a "doing it wrong"-message) is telling you, you're using the wrong hook:

> Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `login_enqueue_scripts` hooks.

Just read about hooks, wrap your code in a callback and then register it properly on one of the three hooks (hint: the one that fits).

Comment: Kaiser Thanks very much your answer helped alot.. i did not added an action it was just hanging out there.